# Changing PS fluid on 2006 Honda Pilot

Tags: honda, pilot, power-steering-fluid

I have a 2006 Honda Pilot in need of power steering fluid change. I do not know the type of power steering fluid in there currently. I've purchased a synthetic. Is it OK to mix power steering fluids if I don't know the type currently in there? Can I use synthetic in a 2006?  I'm a novice so go easy on the responses. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This previous post applies to yours as well
https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/40533/genuine-honda-power-steering-fluid-do-i-have-to-use-this

Comment: Please tell us which specific synthetic product you are hoping to use.

Answer (score 2):

Honda has specific power steering fluid. You don't have to go to a Honda dealership to get some, but you do need to use the specific fluid. I don't know the differences between generic fluid, or even the synthetic fluid you've bought. I don't know what's going to happen to your power steering system if you use the synthetic fluid. I just know it's not specified for your system. If you [Google for Honda Power Steering Fluid](https://www.google.com/search?q=honda+power+steering+fluid&oq=honda+power+steering+fluid) you should be able to find all kinds of examples. This goes for both Honda and Acura power steering systems.

Comment: @Msauce If you use the non-Honda spec fluid, your pump will likely squeal. It depends on the quality of the fluid. The use of incorrect fluid is the primary reason for Honda/Acura pump failures.

Answer (score 0):

So long as the colour of the two liquids are the same, you're usually okay, though this is a massive minefield of opinion-based blasting of theoretical perfect practices versus realistic outcomes.

Mixing two different power steering fluids is a bad idea, though in some cases where well experienced mechanics do it, it's often to do with the age and state of the system; Some mechanics can know whether a specific blend of the two would be beneficial and safe to use.

Should be fine in your era of vehicle. A cool note about your car, by the way, is that in the UK, it's called a Honda CR-V. Looking online at the spec sheets, synthetic should be suitable.

Some cars use a different type, though I'm not so certain how many different types there are, despite being a mechanic for a while, lol. Just make sure to cycle the fluid through the whole system; Top off the PAS bottle and turn the wheel lock to lock a couple of times and check the level again. Repeat again; if you see drop for that second time, you may or may not have a relatively serious leak.  If it's just a change, make sure that you buy more fluid than you'll need; Try and get out any of the old fluid you can from the filler bottle and fill with new fluid. Open the valve at the PAS (not sure how it's set up on those cars) and then cycle fluid through, checking it's got enough in the filler bottle and keep cycling it through until it's coming out with the fresh fluid.

Good luck!

Comment: In the US the Pilot and CR-V are two different trucks.

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting. I guess the Pilot is either a higher-/lower-spec version of the CR-V or vica-versa.

Comment: Im pretty sure the frames are different too the body is different for sure.

Comment: The CR-V uses the same subframe as the Civic, it's a lifted car. The Pilot is closer to a traditional truck but has a spaceframe. It has strengthening rails to supprort light truck work.

Comment: Also, you should never make judgements on color. Easiest example is brake fluid, they're all clear, but they have very different boiling points and properties. Use the wrong fluid (the right color, clear) and you're gonna have a massive brake failure when it over heats and blows a hose.

Comment: @yollooool - In the States, the [CR-V is a small crossover SUV](https://www.caranddriver.com/honda/cr-v) while [the Pilot could be considered a mid-sized SUV](https://www.caranddriver.com/honda/pilot).